# Nested-routes is not working in vue-router 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Here is the codes.

html

```
<div id="app">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <router-link to="/user">User List</router-link>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Routes definition

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/user', component: User,
    children: [
        {path: '', name:'user-list', component: UserList},
        {path: ':id', name: 'user-detail', component: UserDetail}
    ]
}];
let router = new VueRouter({routes});
export default router;
```

User

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>User Center</h2>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods:{
    }
}
</script>
```

User list

```
<template>
<div>
    <!--<ul>-->
        <!--<li v-for="u of userList">-->
            <!--<router-link :to="{ name:'user-detail', params: { id: '4343' }}">{{u.name}}</router-link>-->
        <!--</li>-->
    <!--</ul>-->
    <router-link :to="{ name:'user-detail', params: { id: '4343' }}">3434</router-link>
    <!--<a @click="query">++++</a>-->
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
import {USER_QUERY} from '../store/user.type'


export default {
    data () {
        return {
            userList: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        query: function () {
            this.$store.dispatch(USER_QUERY, [{name:'111'},{name:'1222'}])
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

User detail

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>{{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        test: ()=> {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

I want click the link in the UserList can navitage to the UserDetail,but it is not working,someone help to check it?
Like this

App

--User

----UserList

http://localhost:8080/#/user

change to

App

--User

----UserDetail

http://localhost:8080/#/user/5454

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake like this.

```
import User from './component/user-list.vue';
```

Comment: What was the error here. Could you be more specific please ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to give path in `to` in `outer-link` as `/user/:id` in your HTML code, like following:

```
  <router-link :to="'/users/' + id">3434</router-link>
```

See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/he3ko5m2/2/).

Comment: not working ,its the same,and I also cannot figure out why  <h2>User Center</h2> in User-Center not displayed.